# Where can I find electron forge config js file where package.json is parsed?

Tags: package.json, electron-forge, electron-notarize

I'm looking to use environment variables to store my apple user credentials, but the issue is with Electron Forge this is added to the `package.json` file which doesn't accept those variables. I'm looking for the `.js` file that parses the `package.json` file so I can replace the values with `process.env` variables.

I found the `osxNotarize` JS file but it takes the arguments from another module and while I THINK I could just insert them there, I don't want to break any of the logic that comes before or after that. I'd rather just get to the earliest point that the `.json` file is parsed and insert my variables there.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be crazy to modify the Electron forge source, you should rather extract the electron forge configuration in a separate JS file : [ElectronForge configuration](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration) and load your `environment variables` using `process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME`

[image]