# electron-forge: securely add appleId and password

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to package my electron app, using electron-forge. In order to make the app available on macs, I need to codesign the app, which requires passing info such as appleId and app-specific-password in the package.json file.

**How can I pass this information securely?** (ie, not available to people who download the app)

If environmental variables are the way to go, I'm hoping to understand where I set the environmental variables (in a separate file? In the start command?) and how I access them in the package.json itself.

I'd appreciate any help to sort this out.

---

Details of what I've considered:

-The electron forge [codesign documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/code-signing) does not mention how to actually provide osx required details in a secure way. It does mention that it uses electron-notarize (among others) under the hood, and electron-notarize's [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize) says: "Never hard code your password into your packaging scripts, use an environment variable at a minimum", but doesn't provide detail on how to do that.

-This stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580218/can-i-use-environment-variables-in-electron-package-json-for-osx-notarize-creden) provides helpful info in terms of setting up a separate `forge.config.js` file, and then says you should "load your environment variables using process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME". It doesn't provide more detail--loading the environmental variables for a packaged app is what I'm trying to figure out here.

--This stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214340/electron-builder-how-to-set-node-environmental-variables) mentions setting them manually, but doesn't mention how. It also mentions using the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)--but I'd be surprised there's a separate package required for this task that is fundamental to any mac electron app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been able to hear back from one of the maintainers of electron forge, who said the way to do it is:

- Load the environmental variables in the build script itself. For example:  `$ VAR1=something VAR2=somethingelse npm run make`.
- Then, reference those variables as appropriate in the forge.config.js file that package.json refers to. Example reference syntax: `process.env.VAR1`

Comment: the variables are not accesible into the executable

Answer (score 4):

I store them in an `.env` file in my project directory as follows:

```
APPLEID=your_id
APPLEIDPASS=your_password
```

In `package.json` I have a section:

```
  "build": {
    "productName": "PRODUCT",
    "appId": "your app id",
    "copyright": "Copyright",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "afterSign": "scripts/notarize.js",
```

The `afterSign` points to a script `scripts/notarize.js` that will pull out the `APPLEID` and `APPLEIDPASS` using `dotenv`:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { notarize } = require('electron-notarize')

exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return
  }

  const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;

  return await notarize({
    appBundleId: 'your app id',
    appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
    appleId: process.env.APPLEID,
    appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLEIDPASS
  })
}
```

It's those 2 last lines with `appleId` and `appleIdPassword` that pull out the environment variables.

Never commit the `.env` file to, for example, github. To make sure: add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file. Also: the `script/notarize.js` app is not part of your app itself, this runs while you build your app.

Comment: I also appreciate that you provided your method for notarizing--how to actually activate the notarize process is another thing that is not documented often.